# Running security patch isn't working

Tags: magento2, php, server-setup, security-patch

I tried multiple times running `patch -p1 ACSD-47578_2.4.4_2.4.5_COMPOSER_patch.composer.patch`, even after running full server build on Magento root, but it seems to be stuck as seen in the image below. Our store is running Open source 2.4.4

[image]

Comment: any particular reason why you're not using the quality patches tool? https://experienceleague.adobe.com/tools/commerce-quality-patches/index.html

Comment: But I'm talking about security patches.

Comment: No, it is stuck there. Nothing appears after the command was run

Comment: you can also use the quality patches module to apply "custom" patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing `<` between `patch` and `<path_file>`.

The correct command is:

```
patch -p1 < ACSD-47578_2.4.4_2.4.5_COMPOSER_patch.composer.patch
```

Comment: patch -p1 < ACSD-47578_2.4.4_2.4.5_COMPOSER_patch.composer.patch This returns no such file or directory error

Comment: I did put the file in Magento root as the image above shows

Comment: Please check the patch file once more time for sure, it does now not exist.

Comment: Worked, thanks Tu Van

Comment: I need to check whether the patch applied successfully.

Comment: Glad to help! You can open the patch file, and take a look, `-` indicates removing from the file, `+` indicates adding to the file. Then open the file pached (eg: vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/js/customer-data.js`) to see if the change from the patch file is applied or not.

Comment: Thank you for the help.